# VS Code automatically changes language to JavaScript from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, settings

I am coding with react on my Visual Studio Code. It is always turning the language to JavaScript from React JS and I have to manually change it back. The issue is only on my work PC, on my home PC everything is alright. So I'm sure there is a way to fix it but I can't figure it out. Hoping on your help.

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution i found, is to have different workspace based on the language I'm coding with

Save a React Workspace
[SaveWorkspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsoLl.png)

Then save another one for other scripts

Keep Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

You can constantly set you language setting acording to file type so go to
settings > and type "file language" in searchbar:

[image]

So lets say you want to setup language for js and jsx file you should config it like this:
[image]

see details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file